# How to cut polygon or split polygon using polyline and ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, .net

I have ArcMap10.1 and ArcObject.net.

i have created tool and on mouse down event i write some code I tried it using **topologicalOperator4.Cut2(newPolyline)** but i get error **"A polygon cut operation could not classify all parts of the polygon as left or right of the cutting line."**
i also tried with **topologicalOperator4.Cut** but this method requires 3 parameter

1. polyline
2. LeftGeometry
3. RightGeometry

I have polyline but where should i get this remaining two param values?

this is my polygon which i have to divide into two part where user will create polyline
[image: Polygon Which i have to divide]

Comment: i have create polyline using this code " IPolyline newPolyline = (IPolyline)rubberBand.TrackNew(screenDisplay, (ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.ISymbol)symbol);" and cut it using this code " ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ITopologicalOperator4 topologicalOperator4 = selectedpolygon as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ITopologicalOperator4; // Dynamic Cast
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometryCollection geometryCollection = topologicalOperator4.Cut2(newPolyline);"

Comment: I believe you need to provide two 'empty' IGeometry objects as your other two parameters which will be assigned your 'left' and 'right' polygons. Also if you're having issues trying to cut, I would suggest calling ITopologicalOperator.Simplfy on your polygon to ensure topology information is correct.

Comment: @thehealingprocess=there is only one polygon which is to be divided into two seperate polygons using polyline that's it nothing else.

Comment: @user26464 I'm perfectly aware of that. Try reading my comment more carefully. Your OUTPUT will consist of two polygons, but you need to tell the cut method what variables to assign these polygons to.

Comment: Your polygon, is it some massive multi-part polygon created say from a raster to polygon conversion? I had a similar error message when I was cutting such data manually. The problem was that even though I thought I was cutting across a polygon it was actually across some donut hole. Your cutting line has to going into a polygon then out of it.

Comment: I would also double check to make sure your polyline geometry is valid. It might be helpful if you post more of your code

Comment: i tried but its not working so if any one having sample code regarding this then comment it.

Comment: post a screenshot of your polygon then..i think this is a data issue with either the polygon or the polyline..

Comment: IGeometry left;IGeometry right;  topologicalOperator.Cut(newPolyline,out left,out right);           but that error is still going displayed "Not classified...." because of left and right geometry is null? give some ideas on this

Comment: @thehealingprocess=i solved all error but the changes not reflected in mapcontrol. it will create left and right geometry.any sample is available for this..